# Strange rendering issue occurring in IE8 only

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I'm having some strange rendering issues that are occurring only on IE8, not IE7, 6, or any of the other browsers I've tested (ff, chrome, opera mostly).

http://www.sealymattressonline.co.uk/Shop/Sealy-Silver-Collection-C246/

in IE8 scroll down to the bottom of that page (or indeed any of the other category links from the left sidebar) and on the first pageload there is an un-explained whitespace gap on random products
(see http://plixi.com/p/92068948)

All I need to do is highlight/select the dodgy render with the cursor, or refresh the page, and it renders correctly from then on.
(see plixi.com/p/92069037 for how it looks once it's been "fixed" by highlighting / refreshing the page)

I know that it's not my PC - I've tried several different PCs at my workplace and all do the same on IE8 - so not a browser plugin like some similar problems. I'm also unable to test IE9, as I'm on XP.

Any ideas at all? The winning helper will get cookies (imaginary cookies are yum!)

UPDATE:

I can't reproduce this on my machine's local server or another test server. It doesn't make any sense that this might be a server related error??!

Comment: re the update: when you test locally, have you made sure that you're in the same rendering mode as when you view it remotely -- sometimes IE8 defaults to IE7-compatibility mode when viewing local pages. Open the IE dev tools (F12), and look at the info line at the top to check the rendering mode.

Comment: Good tip, both IE8mode when checked though. Ta.

Answer (score 0):

This style seems to be the culprit:

```
.group {display:inline-block;}
```

I don't see why you need that.
It spans the width of its container, so normal old block should do. You could probably leave off the declaration altogether, as "block" is default for divs.

In IE8 developer tools, I changed display to "block" and the white-space disappeared without any side effects.

Comment: I haven't yet been able to find any IE8 bug descriptions that account for this, but I like to stay on top of these things; so I'll post a link if I can dig up a proper explanation later.

Comment: Thanks for your input.I'm not entirely sure this is it; the reason it disappeared may be that the page auto reloaded, triggering one of the conditions that fixes the weird render anyway.

Comment: sorry, got cut off partway through there. Once it's cached (at least I presume this is it) no matter how many times you go back to the page, it'll render fine. I've overridden the weirdly rendering element to display as a block and the error still occurs; changing its parent gets more tricky as it makes the page float to the left rather than sit in the centre. Will try some more tweaks on the inline block bit just in case.

Comment: updated the main question. Unable to reproduce this on other servers for some reason